# How Would a Venom Symbiote Propel Itself or Even Move at All

Tags: science-based, biology, aliens, xenobiology

What organs or muscular system would a Klyntar alien symbiote like Venom need to move freely as to appear almost or completely liquid? It needs to be able to rearrange, operate without a skeletal system, and be capable of formidable strength.

Comment: What is formidable strength? An ant can lift several times its own weight, though small in absolute magnitude

Comment: Timelapse video of slime molds show them moving much like the fictional alien... but at a pace much too slow for a summer blockbuster.

Comment: @JohnO `but at a pace much too slow for a summer blockbuster.` this summer may be slow enough to worth a try. I mean, look, you can binge movie streaming in corona isolation and doze off without the risk of waking up and panicking over "what did I lose?"

Comment: Anything Marvel and `science-based` are incompatible.

Comment: Not necessarily, Adrian. Just because the Marvel comics don’t provide a “science-based” explanation for all their ideas doesn’t mean the fans can’t do so. Isn’t that the whole purpose of this website anyways, providing possible explanations for the unexplained?

Comment: @CapillaryCumorah `or all their ideas doesn’t mean the fans can’t do so.` show me one that can stand solidly on `science-based`.

Comment: @CapillaryCumorah That's the other SE. This is for stuff for new worlds that askers are building themselves. To explain someone else's, you want sciencefiction.SE.

Answer (score 3):

I was inspired by the Klyntar and came up with a system. I am not sure how well it'd work, but here it goes.

Premise:

The symbiote is made up of many small cells like earth life, but they are all connected by a matrix of long chained molecules similar to PolyEthylene Glycol.

Locomotion:

PEG is a 'self-syphoning fluid' i.e. it can 'pour itself'. This fluid is not a liquid but a kind of 'molecular spaghetti'.

Our symbiont would be held together by something like this. The cells pull the chains taught or even retract them completely to contract, and they let the chain slack to expand.

Durability:

This obviously wouldn't be particularly sturdy. Perhaps the cells, when needed, secrete a glue or epoxy-like substance to harden and create a temporary bone/shell.

Strength:

This would depend on the pulling ability/speed of the cells and the strength of the chains.

Rearranging:

The symbiote doesn't rearrange itself per se. Each cell is something like a stem cell but reversible and fast. What looks like a face is actually just the same cells as the surrounding tissue just reconstituted.

So, it simply dissolves(?) the old limb and replaces it somewhere else giving the illusion of the limb being moved.

Comment: Let's start with something simple, shall we? How does it obtain energy? What does it eat? How is the energy distributed to the cells that need it the most at a certain moment?

Comment: The question is about movement, not energy consumption.